# Why my angular directive doesn't work?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a directive that is triggered when clicking on a button. The function inside the directive simply has to change the property value of the field. So what I try to do is to change from 'popover-trigger="blur"' to 'popover-trigger="none"'.

Here is my plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/L81fQgi7j1dEtf1QAZJ2?p=preview

or the code is here:

```
var app = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('PopoverDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.dynamicPopover = {
        content: 'Hello, World!',
        templateUrl: 'myPopoverTemplate.html',
        title: 'Title'
    };
    $scope.label = "Please click";
    $scope.message = "ON FOCUS trigger a tooltip";

    $scope.htmlPopover = "myPopoverTemplate.html";
});

app.directive("changeTrigger", function($compile){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs)
        {
            elm.bind('click', function(){
                var t = document.getElementsByClassName('f')[0].setAttribute('popover-trigger', 'none');

            $compile(t);
            console.log("Click works");
        });
    }
}

});
```

html

```
<div ng-controller="PopoverDemoCtrl">
    <br><br><br>
    <p>{{message}}</p>
    <input class="f" type="text" value="Click me!" uib-popover-template="htmlPopover" popover-trigger="focus" popover-popup-close-delay="1000" popover-placement="right" required>

    <test-directive></test-directive>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myPopoverTemplate.html">
        <div>
            <p>Click the button to stop triggering tooltip!</p>
            <button change-trigger><b style="color: red">Stop tooltip</b></button>
            <div class="label label-success">page</div>
        </div>
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reconfigure the angular-bootstrap Popup element by changing `uib-popup-*` parameters; but you can bind a scope variable to `popup-enable` attribute to be able to switch the popup on/off. Add:

```
<input ... uib-popover-template="htmlPopover" popover-enable="enable" ...>
```

and

```
$scope.enable = true;
```

The problem here is that your button and the input box have different scopes. But you can fix this by retrieving the scope of the field:

```
var t = document.getElementsByClassName('f')[0];
var scope_ = angular.element(t).scope();
```

Of course, you need to use `$scope.$apply` for the scope to correctly handle two-way data binding:

```
scope_.$apply(function () {
    scope_.enable = false;
});
```

[Working Plunkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/caL62mIjPhALswK3O2DQ?p=preview)

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot. it seems I was looking for the solution in wrong place